# ArangoDB and gremlin: How to reduce LOGGING

Tags: gremlin, arangodb, tinkerpop, gremlin-server, tinkerpop-blueprint

I have installed gremlin  (v. 2.6.0) and ArangoDB (v. 2.8.11) and when I run any request through the `gremlin.sh` shell I get all the debug messages like

```
11:17:39.713 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [REQ]http-GET: url=http://localhost:8529/_api/gharial/myDB/edge/E/12712, headers={}
11:17:39.716 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [RES]http-GET: statusCode=200
11:17:39.716 [main] DEBUG com.arangodb.http.HttpManager - [RES]http-GET: text={"error":false,"code":200,"edge":{"_id":"E/12712"," . . .
```

I see those are DEBUG messages, so I want to suppress in order not to be flooded by those and only get important messages, like errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce logging one has to change the log level on both server and client side.

Complete steps to fix this:

1. create config `PATH_TO/confs/` directory with inside:
       a. file `confs/arangod.conf`
       b. file `confs/logback.xml`
2. set env. variable `CLASSPATH`:

`export CLASSPATH=PATH_TO/confs`

3. you can start `arangod` as   follows:

`arangod  --daemon --pid-file /etc/arangodb/arangodb.pid -c PATH_TO/confs/arangod.conf`

The content of  `confs/arangod.conf` should contain:

```
  [log]
  ## info, warning, or error
  level = info
  file = PATH_TO/logs/arangodb.log
```

The content of the  `confs/logback.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <!-- Arango log4j conf -->
  <appender name="CONSOLE"
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
          <!-- deny all events with a level below INFO, that is TRACE and DEBUG -->
           <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                <level>INFO</level>
           </filter>
           <encoder>
           <pattern>
                 %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{30} - %msg%n
           </pattern>
           </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="DEBUG">
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```